# I'm trying to make a discord music bot but none of the commands work when I type it into discord

Tags: python

I keep getting the error "Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: command "join" is not found

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
   def __init__(self, client):
       self.client = client

@commands.command()
async def join(self,ctx):
 if ctx.author.voice is None:
  await ctx.send("You have to be in a voice channel to listen to music")
 voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
 if ctx.voice_client is None:
  await voice_channel.connect()
 else:
  await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

  @commands.command()
  async def disconnect(self,ctx):
      await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

  @commands.command()
  async def play(self,ctx,url):
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url,download=False)
      url2 = info ['formats'][0]['url']
      source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
      vc.play(source)

@commands.command()
async def pause(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.pause()
    await ctx.send("Paused")

@commands.command()
async def resume(self,ctx):
      await ctx.voice_client.resume()
      await ctx.send("Resumed")

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Sorry if I posted this wrong, I've never used Stack overflow before
and just a beginner with code.

Comment: Watch your spacing and indentation there. Python is very strict about that.

Comment: join, pause and resume should have same level of indentation as init, play and disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Your spacing and indentation should be the same level (join pause and resume should be the same level as init disconnect and play)